# Oracle Object containing list of same object

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm currently struggling with a PL/SQL problem, and Ididn't find a clear answer yet. The problem is, I have an object of type T, which can contain a list of objects of same type T.

Let's say I have a type TPerson. TPerson is defined by a name, and a list of children. So I have a grandfather, his two sons, and the first one has 2 daughters.

In PL/SQL, after some researches, I did this :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TPerson IS OBJECT 
    (
     Name             VARCHAR2(30),
     Children         REF TPersonList,
     constructor function TPerson(name VARCHAR2) return self as result
    );

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE body TPerson as
   constructor function TPerson(aname VARCHAR2) return self as result is
       begin
           Name       := aname;
           Children   := TPersonList();
           return;
       end;
   end;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TPersonList IS TABLE OF REF TPerson';
```

Everything runs with no exception. But the TPerson type does not compile correctly, and I have this compilation error:

```
pls-00532 target of ref must be a complete or incomplete object type
```

It's the first time I use this REF thing. I'm not even sure I'm using it correctly. In my opinion, it's not a really good way to do that (the 'Children' thing), but I don't have the choice. So if someone could explain me a proper way to achieve that, that would help me a lot...

Comment: This is syntactically not correct you are trying to reference an type that's isn't exist and while creating the type you are referring the object which doesnot exist. You need to make a complete definition of one at the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if an object type can have a member of collection of the same type as one have to be able to define the collection before the object type and object type before the collection. To break the circular dependency one needs to introduce a level of indirection in the following fashion (warning non-tested pseudocode follows):

```
-- supertype
create type object_t is object;
create type object_list_t is table of ref object_t;

-- subtype
create type person_t under object_t (
 name varchar2(20)
,children object_list_t
);
```

And then in the implementation of person_t you use [`treat`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11822/adobjbas.htm#ADOBJ7164) to narrow down from supertype to subtype.

Another idea is to have the relations of the objects in a specific relation table. See the example below.

First create a simple person-type:

```
create type person_t is object (
 name varchar2(20)
);
/
show errors

create table persons of person_t;

insert into persons values(person_t('Grandfather'));
insert into persons values(person_t('Father'));
insert into persons values(person_t('Mother'));
insert into persons values(person_t('Son 1'));
insert into persons values(person_t('Daughter 1'));
insert into persons values(person_t('Son 2'));
```

Second create a table for parent-child relations:

```
create table x (
 parent ref person_t
,child ref person_t
);

-- build a family tree
insert into x values(
 (select ref(p) from persons p where name = 'Grandfather')
,(select ref(p) from persons p where name = 'Father')
);

insert into x values(
 (select ref(p) from persons p where name = 'Father')
,(select ref(p) from persons p where name = 'Son 1')
);

insert into x values(
 (select ref(p) from persons p where name = 'Father')
,(select ref(p) from persons p where name = 'Son 2')
);

insert into x values(
 (select ref(p) from persons p where name = 'Father')
,(select ref(p) from persons p where name = 'Daughter 1')
);

insert into x values(
 (select ref(p) from persons p where name = 'Mother')
,(select ref(p) from persons p where name = 'Son 1')
);

insert into x values(
 (select ref(p) from persons p where name = 'Mother')
,(select ref(p) from persons p where name = 'Son 2')
);

insert into x values(
 (select ref(p) from persons p where name = 'Mother')
,(select ref(p) from persons p where name = 'Daughter 1')
);
```

Now you can traverse the family tree with a good old SQL.

```
column parent format a30
column child format a30

select deref(child) as child from x where deref(parent).name = 'Father';

CHILD(NAME)
------------------------------
PERSON_T('Son 1')
PERSON_T('Son 2')
PERSON_T('Daughter 1')

select deref(parent) as parent, deref(child) as child
from x
start with deref(parent).name = 'Grandfather'
connect by prior child = parent
;

PARENT(NAME)                   CHILD(NAME)
------------------------------ ------------------------------
PERSON_T('Grandfather')        PERSON_T('Father')
PERSON_T('Father')             PERSON_T('Son 1')
PERSON_T('Father')             PERSON_T('Son 2')
PERSON_T('Father')             PERSON_T('Daughter 1')
```

The `ref` and `deref` functions are explained in [Database Object-Relational Developer's Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11822/toc.htm). That's a document you should be familiar with if you're working with Oracle object types.

Comment: Well, that's an awesome answer! As I said, the method was kind of imposed to me, but since it does not work... I will submit this method to my manager. Thanks a lot !

Comment: @Mastard Nice to hear you found the example useful. However please pay attention to the performance. I have never used this feature so I don't know what are the performance impacts selecting refs (e.g. in `where deref(parent).name = 'Father'`).